# error installing yeoman on debian jessie

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, keystonejs

I am using a fresh install of Debian 8 Jessie. I installed Nginx, Nodejs 4x,NPM,and MongoDB. I attempted to install Yeoman with `npm install -g yo`. I pressed enter to output yo-complete to STDOUT. I then ran `yo-complete`. Next i installed `npm install -g generator-keystone`. When i try to use the generator `yo keystone` in a project i get the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:163:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

FYI, I am logged in as root, but i understand the problem is that npm runs as no user/group. I never had this problem on ubuntu, but for whatever reason i'm having it now on Jessie. I am at a loss for where i should start in trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: One way to resolve this would be to install nvm and use that to manage your Node install - something I would personally recommend. That would mean you wouldn't need to install anything as root.

Comment: I'm sorry? I use nvm and in my experience it's a lot less grief than a system-wide install

Comment: There's a way to [use it globally](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps).

Comment: I don't understand how nvm helps me accomplish this

Comment: Using NVM means you'd install Yeoman and the generator in your home folder using your user account, making the permissions a non-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my issue was being logged in as root.

i did the following steps:

1. `apt-get autoremove nodejs`
2. `adduser dev` *fill out user details in prompt*
3. `visudo` and uncomment the line allowing sudo group to execute commands as root.
4. `usermod -aG sudo dev` add user to sudo group
5. `su - dev` switch to dev user
6. `sudo apt install nodejs`
7. `sudo npm install -g npm` to update npm
8. `sudo npm install -g yo` reinstall yo
9. install your generators

Worked like a charm, Yo is working with no problems now.